# Adding classes to pseudo-elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

So I'm using pseudo-elements to use a custom checkmark SVG, like this:

```
.thing:before {
    content: " ";
    background: $tickMarkURL;
    background-size: 1.5em;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

(note: this actually uses SCSS, so that's why there's $variables.)

I want to use Animate.css to animate this checkmark into place. However, Animate.css uses classes to add animations to elements. I don't think that's possible with this pseudo-element (I think). Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the `animation` in the `animate.css` file and simply add it in the `:before` `scss`

```
.thing:before {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  animation-name: bounce;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```

Comment: There are no stupid questions :) Don't forget to accept this life saving answer though ;)